# Get canvas size in custom view with hardwareAcceleration set to false

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-view, android-custom-view

When I set the hardware acceleration to `false` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` with `hardwareAccelerated="false"` the method `canvas.getWidth()` or `canvas.getHeight()` falls back to a weird behaviour:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int h = canvas.getHeight();
    int w = canvas.getWidth();
}
```

- If hardware acceleration is **on**: `h` = height of view & `w` = width of view (e.g. 500x500)
- If hardware acceleration is **off**: `h` = height of screen & `w` = width of screen (e.g. 1080x1920)

How can I get the dimensions of my view when `hardwareAcceleration` is `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the dimensions of my view when `hardwareAcceleration` is `false`?

Canvas size has nothing to do with `View`'s size. If you want to get size of the view inside `onDraw()` you can use [`getMeasuredWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredWidth())/[`getMeasuredHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight()).

Comment: but why is the view size returned when hardwareAcceleration is true?

Comment: Cannot answer to that question. It seems like an implementation detail on which we, as developers, should not depend on. What is your use case? Why exactly you need underlying `Canvas`'s size and **not** the `View`'s size?

Comment: I dont need exactly to differenciate the two sizes. My on draw method relies on the width and height in px of the view, because inside i draw with percentual values. therefore i need the exact measures of the width and height.

`getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()` might work fine, i'll try out in a few mins